# Are Yajuj Majuj on earth?

Tags: quran, hadith, islamic-philosophy, universe, yajooj-and-majooj

I've heard that the nation of Yajuj and Majuj (Gog and Magog) is in the ratio 999:1 to humans, meaning there are 999 of them for every human. There are approximately 7.8 billion humans on the earth today. This would mean there are approximately 7792.2 billion of the Yajuj and Majuj, which is a number beyond human comprehension. It seems impossible for such a large group to remain hidden and undiscovered for so long. So are the Yajuj and Majuj really on earth or are they in a completely different place? If they are on earth, how is this possible?

Comment: Can you mention the reference from where you got that ratio 999:1 ?

Comment: Bukhari 3348 says 999 and Fath-ul-Bari says this: Narrated Ibn Umar: ‘Allah Divided mankind into ten parts. Nine tenths constitute Gog and Magog while the remaining one tenth constitutes the rest of mankind.’” (Ibn Hajar al-Asqalani, Fath ul-Bari)

Comment: While it may seem incomprehensible that such a large number of individuals can remain hidden for so long, we just need to remember the number of angels and jinns that Allah has created is far larger. There is only a certain range of light that our eyes can see in and only a slightly larger range of the light spectrum that we have been able to detect through our gadgets. There are dimensions Allah has kept in Ghaib from us & will reveal only when He pleases.

Comment: So are you trying to say that Yajuj Majuj are not humans?

Answer (score 1):

“Bring me sheets of iron" - until, when he had leveled [them] between the two mountain walls, he said, "Blow [with bellows]," until when he had made it [like] fire, he said, "Bring me, that I may pour over it molten copper." - (The Holy Qur’an 18:96)

When Zulqarnain built the wall he could only build it in one place, the earth. This quote signifies that as he got people who he stumbled across to bring him these materials in which the wall was made. The location is unknown, many come up with theories but ignore them as they are merely theories. They are hidden for a reason and they will be released closer to the day of judgement. Although I can understand why you think that but there are many other hadiths which further explain the events of yajuj and majuj.

Comment: What about satellite images of the earth?

Comment: Nothing can see the location of yajuj and majuj except Allah and Isa AS when he comes back on earth.